# Book on Lipschitz continuity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, book-recommendation

I have managed to end up in a fourth-year differential equations class without ever needing to take analysis (really think they messed the pre-reqs up). I know the notions of bounded, closed, compact, and convergent sequences, continuity and even uniform continuity. But give me a ball of radius $r$ at $x$ and all I know how to do with it is play soccer.

I would like a good book that lays out different types of continuity and proves their relationship, preferably also with examples being applied to actual functions on the reals. (Turns out there is like 6 different types of continuity. And I really don’t want to drop this class if I can help it.)

Comment: The title and the body of your question seems rather different. In the title you say you want something about Lipschitz continuity. (BTW this would suggest using ([tag:lipschitz-functions]) tag.) But in the body of the questions you say that you wan something about various types of continuity.

Comment: I guess a correct choice of words would be im trying to prepare for a 4th year course on advanced differential equations. my prof has no textbook and no references given as of yet and this was the first thing i haven't understood well. oh and i have never taken an analysis class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Re: *Lipschitz* continuity, I suggest you look at Fig. 29 in [Arnold (1992)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=JUoyqlW7PZgC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA38#v=onepage&q&f=false) and the discussion around it. Myself, I think about the Lipschitz property as more of a weakened smoothness condition than a strengthened continuity one; the symbol $C^{1-}$ sometimes used for Lipschitz-continuous functions is quite apt. (Note that $C^0 \supset C^{1-} \supset C^1$; about the $C^k$ notation, see [the *MathWorld* article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-kFunction.html) in case you’ve never taken multivariable calculus.)

[image: Image showing that Lipshitz continuous function passes inside a cone centered at a given point, with an acute angle, titled “the Lipschitz condition”.]

Re: other notions of continuity, I’m not sure that you are going to need them all. To enumerate:

- Continuity, I expect you have some understanding of.
- [Uniform continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity) is the same as continuity when you are on a compact set (the [Heine-Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem)). Uniform continuity is what you use to prove Riemann integrability, so a simpler version and applications of this result usually occur somewhere around there in a calculus/analysis course.
- [Absolute continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) mostly appears in connection with Lebesgue integration, so that is where you should go for the explanations. Whether you *need* to depends on the notion of integration used in the ODE course, and if you indeed need to learn a whole new theory of integration then you’ve got bigger problems than continuity notions.
- [Lipschitz continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) I tried to elaborate on above, and it is indeed the notion used for the usual ODE existence and uniqueness theorem, the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).
- [Hölder continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) is a refinement of Lipschitz continuity (look at the definition) used mostly in advanced PDE theory. If you made it to fourth year without real analysis, you will be able to graduate without ever encountering it.
- [Equicontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity) (and uniform equicontinuity, and Lipschitz property with a common constant) is a property of *families* of functions rather than of functions themselves. You should compare it to uniform convergence of functional sequences. It is used in the [Arzelà-Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem), which you *may or may not* end up using in the course.

Aside from continuity, your remarks make me wonder whether you took some kind of multivariable differential calculus. If not, study it, because it is required here. A ball there is just a normal Euclidean ball (possibly $n$-dimensional though), the excercise is mostly to figure out where in the usual calculus proofs you can change a modulus sign into a norm (*i.e.* length) sign, and where you should replace multiplication by a linear map (*i.e.* matrix multiplication). Functional (infinite-dimensional) balls should come afterwards.

Re: the course, brace yourself, because the proofs *are* going to be hard for you. Thankfully, there is not a lot of theorems in a basic ODE course, and the statements are all rather intuitive. Given that you are asking the question at this time of year, I suppose that the course began with the theorems, which is really not a wise choice. (However, if it is really *all* like this, *i.e.* if it is going to proceed into PDE theory, dynamical systems and so on, I strongly suggest you drop it.) Read the first chapters in Arnold’s book to get what you are actually getting at with those statements. (I would even recommend to track down a translation of the *first* Russian edition, because it is much more concise if sparser on applications.)

Comment: i have a notion of continuity from a multivarabile calculus class in third year they discontiued it at my university and split it up into two class's and added an 2nd year analysis course requirement it was kind of a crass course on real analysis for 3 weeks then assume you magically understand it. i managed to understand everything except how to use the actual balls in any application rather well. i managed to understand the process of the proof given in class and its usefulness in application but could never prove it myself even with help.

Comment: @Faust7 Well, neighbourhoods (as used in “low-brow” calculus as opposed to topology) are (open) balls, so I supposed it was balls in function spaces you were having problems imagining. Basically, the application in calculus is that “$x$ tends to $a$” is the same that “$x$ gets is (eventually) in an arbitrarily small ball centered on $a$” (and you get topology when you forget about the *radii* of the balls but keep the balls themselves; *e.g.* continuity but no uniform continuity). I don’t know much about English-language calculus books, but I could try to answer a more concrete question.

Comment: The best i thought i understood it was we were trying to look for something in the preimage of f put a ball of radius $\delta $ around it and show that we could make it smaller than any $\epsilon$ in the image of f. if we could do that it implied continuity inside of that radius in the preimage. i can read an epsilon delta proof but i cannot actually perform one. will i need that in DE's course?

Comment: @Faust7 Technically, no, you could get away with just knowing the results (as elsewhere in mathematics), but I expect you will have problems understanding the subsequent statements.

Comment: @Faust7 Regarding this particular definition (continuity), convince yourself that $\forall \epsilon \exists\delta \forall x. \lVert x-a\rVert < \delta \Rightarrow \lVert f(x)-f(a) \rVert < \epsilon$ is, on one hand, a fancy version of the one-variable case (with distances instead of absolute values—which are, after all, one-dimensional distances), and on the other hand, equivalent to $\forall\epsilon\exists\delta. f(U_\delta(a)) \subseteq U_\epsilon(f(a))$. Draw a picture of the latter, while really thinking about mapping sets rather than individual points.

Comment: Thats actually really hard to to think about i believe $U_{\delta}$ is actually a set of functions and by using composition of these two mappings an some concept of 1-1. Im going to goto bed and have anther look in the morning my eyes have gone cross so to speak. thanks for your help in improving my understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51759/discussion-between-alex-shpilkin-and-faust7).

Comment: Any mention of Arnold's ODE book gets a +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this link has a good introduction on Lipschitz continuity

http://users.wpi.edu/~walker/MA500/HANDOUTS/LipschitzContinuity.pdf.

And for Real Analysis, iI think book by Royden , by S.Kumaresan is really good and student friendly it encourages you to think.